when system overload ’bpf_probe_write_user‘ error is '-14'
I planned to modify the parameters of the lseek function, but I found that when I modified it, bpf_probe_write_user kept returning a -14 error. I don’t know what went wrong.
here is my code:
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_lseek")
int sys_enter_lseek(struct trace_event_raw_sys_enter* ctx)
{
    pid_t pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    if (pid != target_pid)
        return 0;

    int whence = 2;
    
    long ret = bpf_probe_write_user((void*)&(ctx->args[2]), (void*)&whence, sizeof(ctx->args[2]));
    bpf_printk("sys_enter_lseek ret: %d", ret);
    return 0;
}

I have tried parameter modification of other functions, such as filename modification of the open function, and I succeeded. But when I modify non-char* type parameters, an error will be reported. I don’t understand why. Please give me some advice.

from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html

long bpf_probe_write_user(void *dst, const void *src, u32 len)
....
It only works for threads that are in user context, and dst must be a valid user space address.

When dst is point to a number type parameter, that is not a valid user space address but a kernel space address.

So there is no way to modify it?
